# Phonegap+JavaScript+WP7: Doesn't work ajax.responseText

Tags: javascript, ajax, windows-phone-7, cordova

I am using Cordova 1.6.1 and have a problem with html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onDeviceReady() {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("GET","http://mySite.com/response.php",true);
    ajax.send();
    ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(ajax.readyState==4 && (ajax.status==200)){
            console.log("--Start log to VStudio");
            console.log(ajax.responseText);
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            console.log("--End log to VStudio");
        }
    }
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

</script>
```

The problem is that text "--End log to VStudio" will be never shown in spite of text "--Start log to VStudio" is shown always, and content isn't changed. This java script works well in browser (Chrome), but not WP7 phone or emulator.

response.php:

```
<?php
    echo "My new content";
?>
```

I have set .htacces settings so:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Comment: What does console.log(document.getElementById('content')); give you?

Comment: It gives nothing, but  console.log(document.getElementById('content').innerHTML) return "Content to be replaced", so this function works. I have found out that only one line ajax.responseText; could freeze execution.